# How can I center the text but not the number label of an HTML ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am creating a little widget for a page that lists steps in reverse order. I plan on doing this with an `ol` and setting the `value` attribute on the individual `li` tags to force the numbering of the `ol` to be reversed. So far so good.

However, I have a design conundrum that I'm not sure can be solved with css.

**With this mark up, is it possible to center the text but keep the labels left-aligned?**

```
<ol>
    <li value="5">item 5</li>
    <li value="4">item 4</li>
    <li value="3">item 3</li>
    <li value="2">item 2</li>
    <li value="1">item 1</li>
</ol>
```

Here is an image to illustrate the text treatment I am after.

[image: Reversed OL with centered text but left-aligned labels]

It would be a shame if I had to shove extra spans in my markup for something that OLs do automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reverse counters, then you can align the counters separately from the text.

not IE7 though, but with the values it'll default (IE hacks built in get back the defaults)

**CSS:**

```
ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: decimal !ie7;
    margin-left: 20px !ie7;
    counter-reset:item 6; /* one higher than you need */
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ol > li {
    counter-increment:item -1;
    text-align: center;
}
ol > li:before {
    content:counter(item) ". ";
    float: left;
    width: 30px; background: #eee;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li value="5">item 5</li>
    <li value="4">item 4</li>
    <li value="3">item 3</li>
    <li value="2">item 2</li>
    <li value="1">item 1</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That is super awesome! I wasn't aware of counter(item) for the content attribute so I disregarded :before before I should have. Thanks for this.

Comment: @DingoEatingFuzz, you're welcome - yea it's pretty cool what's on our doorstep now, but finding everything is the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need that extra element - the numbers in the list are considered part of the text for layout purposes like this. Adding an inner span set to display: inline-block should do the trick.

On a design note, it's worth pointing out that multiple lines of center-aligned text are very hard to scan, as the starting point (left edge) of the text is in a different place from line to line. Would a consistent, if large, text-indent suit you just as well? It would definitely be more readable.

And FWIW, did you know that HTML5 includes the 'reversed' attribute on OL's? You'll still need your value attributes for older browsers, of course.

Comment: I am aware of the reversed attribute (as of today) but when I tested it out in firebug (with FF4) it didn't work, so I'm holding out. 

As for using text-indent, my fear is that there may be a case where there will be too much text in the item so the indent won't work. Indent or centered, I'm putting myself on shaky ground. Odds are I will eventually have to redesign it to allow for multi-line labels. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Wow - I thought FF4 would have supported it for sure. Good to know - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by shoving extra spans, but this works:

```css
li {text-align:center; margin-bottom:4px;}
#list {display:block;width:300px;background:#ddd;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><div id="list">This is item four</div></li>
    <li><div id="list">This is item three</div></li>
    <li><div id="list">This is item two</div></li>
    <li><div id="list">This is item one</div></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by shoving extra spans (except you used divs). Also, tag ids are supposed to be unique. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
li{ list-style:none; text-align:center; }
li:before{ content:attr(value); float:left; }
```