# Reverse Numbers on list in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to make numbered list in reverse order such as 10,9,8,7
but when i try manually it create problems in formatting.

```
<ol start="10">
<li><strong> Asiate – New York City</strong></li>
```

Is there any plugin or code snippet which i can use in custom css of wordpress theme so i can get a proper numbered box or block in new post because you can get the idea of whole thing behind it here's the site http://toptenzilla.com
Please help me if there's any wordpress expert.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5426130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 `<ol>` comes with an attribute [`reversed`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-ol-reversed) which you can add. You don't need to add anything fancy.

```html
<ol start="10" reversed>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
</ol>
```

Unfortunately in terms of [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#AutoCompatibilityTable), IE and Opera do not support this :(...

For a more cross-browser friendly solution, you'll have to manually set the value

```html
<ol>
  <li value="10">Point</li>
  <li value="9">Point</li>
  <li value="8">Point</li>
  <li value="7">Point</li>
  <li value="6">Point</li>
  <li value="5">Point</li>
  <li value="4">Point</li>
  <li value="3">Point</li>
  <li value="2">Point</li>
  <li value="1">Point</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Then how to get it compatible with other browsers?

Comment: @shoaibyaseen I updated my answer. You have to manually set the value in the `li`s